# What are the slash markings on Gatwick's 08R/26L?

Tags: runways, airport-markings, uk

[image]
[Google Earth @ 51°08'52.24" N   0°11'35.71" W](https://goo.gl/maps/uhSP7HdMJJnoEEqJ8)

The markings are at 100 m intervals, to one side only of the centerline. They're also lighted as seen below.

They are missing from the ICAO aerodrome [chart](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=93&Itemid=142.html), and are not mentioned in [CAP 637](http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?appid=11&mode=detail&id=136) (Visual Aids Handbook).

I measured from each threshold, but the distances to the first in each set don't match. They also don't seem to be new (judging by older satellite imagery).

[image]
[YouTube](https://youtu.be/j3hgfIp_qgw?t=2617)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are "Rapid Exit Taxiway Indicator Lights" as described in section 9.6 of CAP 637.

> 9.6 **Rapid Exit Taxiway Indicator Lights**
>
> 9.6.1 Rapid  exit  taxiway  indicator  lights  (RETILs)  provide  pilots  with  distance  to  go information to the nearest rapid exit taxiway on the runway, to enhance situational awareness  in  low  visibility  conditions  and  enable  pilots  to  apply  braking  action  for more efficient roll-out and runway exit speeds.
>
> 9.6.2 RETILs consist of six yellow lights adjacent to the runway centreline and configured in a three/two/one pattern spaced 100 m apart; the single light is 100 m from the start of the turn for the rapid exit taxiway, see Figure 1.6.

Comment: Right! I was looking under what seemed like the logical place: chapter 2, where the runway markings are.

Comment: They held an [ICAO meeting](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/AMC/Assembly37/Working%20Papers%20by%20Number/wp156_en.pdf) about the missing markings (actual paint, not lights) from ICAO Annex 14, and in the proposal, the lines come with arrow heads.

Comment: If you [zoom into the map](https://goo.gl/maps/uhSP7HdMJJnoEEqJ8), you can see the yellow center-line for the taxiway starts right after the last mark (single slash).

Comment: The same principle as the countdown chevrons on the motorway.